# How do you fix 550 must be authenticated sending Mail using Grails?

Tags: email, grails, smtp

I'm using Grails Mail plugin and trying to send email and keep getting:

> Error 500: Executing action [sendInvite] of controller
>   [RegisterController] caused exception: Failed messages:
>   javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses; nested exception
>   is: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 must be
>   authenticated

I'm properly following the instructions at: http://www.grails.org/Mail+plugin

Comment: what mail server are you connecting to?

Comment: Can you post the applicable portion of your config.groovy and the snippet of code where you're sending the email.

Comment: I've tried both gmail and another mail server. I've followed the examples exactly as far as I can tell. I was hoping someone else has seen the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mail server is returning an error when you try to send out the mail.  [550 is a generic SMTP failure code](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt); in this case it looks like you are missing a username and password.  Some SMTP servers to not require authentication but most do, especially if they're publicly available on the internet.  It's also possible that your SMTP server requires an SSL connection and you're connecting with an unsecured socket.

The [example config for gmail](http://www.grails.org/Mail+plugin#Configuration) shows how to set all the mail server authentication options in Config.groovy:

```
grails {
    mail {
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        port = 465
        username = "youracount@gmail.com"
        password = "yourpassword"
        props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",         
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
    }
}
```

Add `"mail.debug": "true"` to props to turn on JavaMail debugging to get a better picture of what is happening before the failure.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the 550 error was caused by me having accidentally selected and IMAP account as the default account but sending emails from my Outlook Connector Account (which has no authentication settings to make).

I changed the Outlook Connector Account to default. Resent the emails and no errors.

So check that the correct email account is set up as the default also